# How to make a VPN kill-switch for mac OS X

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, ufw, pf

What I wanna do is to have the internet connection disabled completely when the VPN connection goes down. I am connecting to my VPN (privatevpn.com) through Viscosity.

I have tried everything in the book. I have tried to have a disconnect scripts in Viscosity, but they never trigger, or trigger inconsistently and leave my connection vulnerable. I also tried routing tricks in Viscosity but it doesnt work either.

On my Ubuntu machines I have a solution that works perfectly, I use ufw rules to control the firewall. In order to connect to my VPN I need to disable UFW, and then once the VPN have connected I enable UFW, and it keeps the connection tight from leaking.

There is something called pf on Mac. I might be able to configure pf to work the same way as my ufw rules work, but I don´t understand how to configure it.

Here are my UFW rules I would like to run on the Mac as well, maybe someone can help me to configure pf to use the same rules?

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming, deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To              Action              From
Anywhere        ALLOW IN            193.180.119.0/24
Anywhere        ALLOW OUT           193.180.119.0/24

Comment: No Mac networking experts around?

Answer (score 7):

The best thing I have found is to use [PF](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) available on [mac os X](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html), after you connect to your VPN provider just need to change the IP.

Create a file `~/killswitch/pf.conf` containing this

```
# Options
set block-policy drop
set ruleset-optimization basic
set skip on lo0

# Interfaces
wifi = "en1"
vpn = "utun1"

# Block everything
block out all
block in all

# Outbound: Allow only VPN 
pass out on $wifi proto {tcp, udp} from any to 81.171.71.XX

# Allow traffic for VPN
pass out on $vpn all
```

Double check your interfaces, in my case `en1` is the WiFi and `uten1` the VPN tunnel.

Change `81.171.71.XX` to the IP you get when you connect.

enable pf

```
$ sudo pfctl -e
```

Load the rules:

```
$ sudo pfctl -Fa -f /path/to/pf.conf
```

Disable pf:

```
$ sudo pfctl -d
```

I had to implement this due to a issue with ipvanish, mainly because the application was crashing making the VPN to go down and traffic was back to the default, none encrypted route.

## update

You can give a try to [killswitch](https://vpn-kill-switch.com/) it can do all this for you automatically.

Comment: OK thanks, I ended up using AirVPN client for Mac OS X, and it works out of the box. Just in case someone wanna save some time in the future.

Comment: I just tried `killswitch` on macOS 10.12.6 and it works perfectly. Install with `brew install killswitch`. If it fails, try first `brew tap vpn-kill-switch/killswitch` and then install. In this way, it might fail to download the bottle, but it will then compile from source for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could this script do the trick?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true 
do
  result=$(scutil --nc list | grep Connected)
  if [ -z "$result" ]; then
     killall Transmission
     exit
  fi 
done
```